# Constraints in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am learning constraints and spent whole day applying them to the following screen.It is not getting displayed properly in landscape mode.Basically i am not getting how to fix vertical space between ,say, label-Welcome to BBBB and textfield-username so that textfield always appears below the label yet the spacing between them is adjusted according to the screens of different size. If i go for Pin\Vertical space, it automatically fixes the constant value.

[image: username and password are textfields, lines below them are views of height=1, login and forget your password are buttons, create new profile is label, blue image is a button, green one is just an image, gray is a view with an image of fringe attached to its top]

[image]

Comment: did you use storyboard constraints or programming

Comment: Can you clarify - you want the space between the label and the textfield to shrink when the device rotates to landscape?

Comment: You used aspectRatio for this, it will automatically adjust your spacing according to height of your ViewController.

Comment: yes, i want the space to get shrunk when the device rotates to landscape. 2

Comment: i went for storyboard constraints.  @Ali Beadle yes, i want the space to get shrunk when the device rotates to landscape.

Comment: Add please landscape screenShot.

Comment: add constraints image ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ali Beadle was right. Since i had a lot of vertically stacked items, lining them up in landscape mode was not possible. So, i went for scrollview. 
I have taken a ScrollView first and then a UIView named ContentView on that ScrollView. I have made the width of ContentView equal to the width of parent UIView and kept its height fixed to 568. In my code i set

```
_contentViewHeight.constant = self.view.frame.size.height;
```

Now it scrolls in landscape mode while in potrait mode, it does'nt scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the label (or just move it out of the way).

Fill the space that you want to resize with a view.

Constrain this view to the objects above and  below and to the sides of the parent view.

Put your label into this view and constrain it to the top of this view and centred to it.

You may need to change the constraints on the objects above and below it to stop them from changing height in an unwanted manner.

This new view should now resize as the device changes orientation but the label should remain at the top of it.

Repeat on other areas of your layout (i.e put things that are not moving around as you want them into sub views and constrain these views to resize accordingly). Experiment with using variable heights, fixed heigh constraints and 'equal heights with' constraints on the views that you add to get them to resize as you need.

Edit: but you have a lot of vertically stacked items in that view - you may never get them all to fit into a horizontal orientation. You may need to remove a few, or add a scroll view or force that view only to layout in portrait mode or... Don't forget to check that it works on all devices you are targeting.

Answer (score -1):

I run into Autolayout problems all the time. But I finally figured out a way to overcome a lot of issues that arise from it.
I simply will use a container-View like ScrollView or even a plain old UIView, place all my controls in it. thats it. this makes things a lot easier for autolayout to figure out the constraints. in your case you could just use a UIView.

-start off by removing all the constraints you have I would start by selecting each control in the XIB and see if it has width/height constraint, select it then press the delete key then at the bottom of the project explorer you'll see all the constraints that auto layout has select each one then delete. that should get rid of any complaints that auto-layout might have.

-Place a UIView object inside your main View then

-move all the controls inside it. Then

-add the necessary constraints for the container view so it'll resize in different orientations and don't worry about any constraints inside the container view (auto layout will figure them out automatically).

that does the trick for me usually.